# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint Slide Show: Start from This Slide (Shift+F5)

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-addins

I'd like to to implement start slide show as Start from This Slide in C# (for Addin).
Keyboard shortcut is assigned as Shift+F5.

Following code works as start slide show as Start from Beginning.

```
// Works as F5 key (start from beginning)
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```

I tried to use SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide with SlideShowSettings.RangeType = PpSlideShowRangeType.ppShowSlideRange, but it limits the range of slide.
I cannot go back first slide like Shift+F5.

```
// NG code: start from 2nd slide and cannot go back to 1st slide
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.RangeType = PpSlideShowRangeType.ppShowSlideRange;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide = 2;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```

I tried also with SlideShowSettings.RangeType = PpSlideShowRangeType.ppShowAll, but it seems conflict setting.

```
// NG code: I think it gets conflict. Slide shows does not even start.
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.RangeType = PpSlideShowRangeType.ppShowAll;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide = 2;
app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```

Is there way to implement Shift+F5 from C#?
Any recommendation?

Thank you.

Comment: Use your first clode block but try adding the EndingSlide number (you can use `ActivePresentation.Slides.Count` to run to the end of the slides). Or, start your show from the first slide, then "jump" to the fifth slide (`app.ActivePresentation.Slides[4].Select();`).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It seems not working as expected. I want to emulate Shift+F5 function (start slideshow from current selected slide) via API. EndingSlide seems not related this case. Second tips for jump to fifth slide seems not working. It stay on first slide.